# Why did the second coat of my hardwood floor finish blister?

Tags: hardwood-floor

I refinished a 100 yr old wood floor. Both coats were oil based poly. Temperature was relatively consistent, zero moisture. It was cleaned before coating.

First coat was given a full 24 hours to dry before the second coat. The blistering wasn't consistent across the floor. Parts of the floor look great, other parts are not.I can't figure out what went wrong.
[image: floor blistering]

Comment: Did you sand between the coats?

Comment: I agree with stevesh but I will use steel wool just enough to scratch or buff the surface.

Comment: maybe temperature was consistent, but was it within the allowable range?

Comment: I suggest you take a look through the finishing questions at the [woodworking.se] sister site. _Loads_ of info there about finishing and refinishing.

Answer (score 1):

Humidity or thickness or wasn’t dry in some spots… Or perhaps the re-coat time was 4 to 6 hours not 24…

But looks like you need to sand it back and redo it.